# Can anything be done to replace a vulnerable (or otherwise problematic) sub-dependency out of an AAR dependency

Tags: android, aar

Latest version of `androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1` (also `2.8.0-alpha01`) depend on a vulnerable version of protobuf-javalite package:

```
work-runtime-2.7.1.aar: inspector.jar/META-INF/maven/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-javalite/pom.xml (pkg:maven/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-javalite@3.10.0, cpe:2.3:a:google:protobuf-java:3.10.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*) : CVE-2021-22569
```

The vulnerability is 3 weeks old, and there is no indication that an update to address this is coming.

I understand that the way this dependency is packaged, there isn't a way to yank it out of there, and force-feed a newer version in its stead.

Do I have any options left here, besides recompiling the project myself for the time being?